# concatenation and recursion

Tags: python, recursion, operators

```
#Calculates to the index position of a fib number.
def f3(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return f3(n-2) + f3(n-1)
```

The function only accepts one argument, yet two are being sent in the return, yet, it works! What's happening here?

If I return f3(n-3), the function breaks down. What effect does the concatenation have?

Answer (score 5):

Addition results in a single value.

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
>>> [1] + [2]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python evaluates the expression `f3(n-2) + f3(n-1)` before returning it, so its actually returning the value of them combined. The same is the case for `f3(n-2)`, its first evaluating `n-2` and then passing it as a value to `f3()`.

The number of return arguments has nothing to do with the number of arguments a function takes as input.

Comment: When I try to use (n-3) the func breaks down. Why do I have to concatenate two in the return?

Comment: @pythondjango: Where do you see concatenation? There's no concatenation here.

Comment: When you only use `f3(n-3)` instead of `f3(n-2) + f3(n-1)`? Its because of the way the Fibonacci recursion works. 
I think this might be of help understanding how it works: http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/csbsju/cs/160/notes/29/0.html 
.

Comment: @veiset Thanks. You're the only one who understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

The line `f3(n-2) + f3(n-1)` is returning only *one* value, the result of calculating `f3` for the input `n-2` and then adding that value to the result of calculating `f3` for the input `n-1`

In Python, the mechanism for returning multiple values from a function is by packing them inside a tuple and then extracting them at the time of invoking the function (not the case in your question!) For example:

```
def multivalue(x, y)
    return (x, y)

a, b = multivalue(5,10)
# here a holds 5, and b holds 10
```